# Java WebSocket: onMessage is not triggered

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

I have used this [code](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/websocket/javase-client/src/main/java/org/javaee7/websocket/javase/client) to write the websocket client in java. It's a secure socket. Connection to destination is established fine but onMessage is not getting called.

When I write the same thing in java script it's working and able to get response.

Please check my code and advise what am I missing here.

My Code:

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class MyClientEndpoint {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connected to endpoint: " + session.getBasicRemote());
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("subscribe", URLEncoder.encode("xxxxxxx","UTF-8"));
            String msg = obj.toJSONString();
            System.out.println("Sending message to endpoint: " + msg);
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyClientEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received message in client: " + message);
        Client.messageLatch.countDown();
    }



public class Client {

    final static CountDownLatch messageLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            String uri = "wss://api.....";
            System.out.println("Connecting to:: " + uri);
            container.connectToServer(MyClientEndpoint.class, URI.create(uri));
            messageLatch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);            
        } catch (DeploymentException | InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be missing the `Session session` argument in your `@OnMessage`. Signature should be `public void myMethod(Session session, String message);`

Comment: Tried with Session session as first argument to the method but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to connect to secure websocket by passing credentials in

```
ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator configurator = new ClientEndpointConfig.Configurator() {
             public void beforeRequest(Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
          String credentials = "username:password";
          headers.put("Authorization", Arrays.asList("Basic " + new BASE64Encoder().encode(credentials.getBytes())));
                 System.out.println("Header set successfully");
             }
         };

         ClientEndpointConfig clientConfig = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create()
                 .configurator(configurator)
                 .build();
```

I documented the steps in the below link.

https://bigdatatechbytes.blogspot.in/2017/10/java-client-for-secure-web-socket.html